# Is there a way to retain same instances when AWS autoscales up/down the instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We've deployed app in AWS with minimum x instances (with in-memory caching at instance level). When AWS scales down any instance can go down. Is there a way to retain original x instances and AWS should destroy (scale down) the newest instance (last created by AWS)?

Comment: AWS scale up/down policy is affecting our in-memory caching which we doing at instance level.

Comment: No, not possible. You need to store the "state"/"cache" somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

You can protect EC2 instances from termination using the Instance Protection features.

[Instance Protection for Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/)

You can modify EC2 auto scaling with custom termination policies. In your case, select Newest Instance to have the youngest EC2 instances terminate.

This link documents the various features:

[Controlling Which Auto Scaling Instances Terminate During Scale In - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html)

By combining the above two features, you should be able to achieve your objective.

Comment: Is there a way to do it for ECS as well? @john

Comment: If you mean prevent termination of an EC2 instance, yes. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/accidental-termination/

Comment: I learnt something around this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html. This is for ec2 - setting autoscale policy - delete newer instance first. Same I'm looking for ECS?

Comment: Oh, I see you just swapped the `amazon-ec2` tag to the `amazon-ecs` tag. The above information is only relevant for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling.